# conflicting options string(s) on second loop

Tags: python, youtube-api, arguments, argparse

```
    #main loop 
while 1==1:
    #If they click Yes on the dialog box begin recording, otherwise ask again
    easygui.msgbox('This is what the last person suggested! Press ok to record.: ' + output_string, 'Title', ok_button= "OK")
    N+=1
    counterFile = open('counterFile','w')
    counterFile.write(str(N));
    counterFile.close()
    camera.start_recording('video' + str(N) + '.h264')
    audioRecord() 
    camera.stop_recording()
    output_string_old = output_string;
    output_string = TextEnter()
    filename = ConvertMerge()
    argparser.add_argument("--file")
    argparser.add_argument("--title")
    argparser.add_argument("--description")
    argparser.add_argument("--category")
    argparser.add_argument("--keywords")
    argparser.add_argument("--privacyStatus")
    args = argparser.parse_args(["--file", filename, "--title", str(N),"--description", output_string_old, "--category", "22", "--keywords", " ", "--privacyStatus", "public"])
    initialize_upload(get_authenticated_service(args), args)
```

I've made this code which records footage and then uploads to youtube using the youtube api but it currently returns this error on the second loop around.

> ArgumentError: argument --file: conflicting options string(s): --file

`filename ='mergedVideo'+ str(N) + '.mkv'` and increases each time the programme is run.

Why is this error happening on the second loop around?

Comment: Can you include the loop in your code?

Comment: @Sweater-Baron does that help? i'm a very amateur coder so this is probably very messy....

Comment: The code that you just posted seems to have lost its indentation. Or is the code not indented in your source files either?

Comment: @Sweater-Baron sorry that was an error in me copying it in. sorted! any other questions about the code im more than happy to answer.

Comment: First time through you added a set of `arguments` to an existing `argparser` (created I believe by the `youtube` api).  You can't add more arguments of the same name.  You can call `parse_args` again, but you can't reuse `add_argument('--file'...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling parser.add_argument("--file") multiple times, when you must only call it once per argument. Just move all of the add_argument calls to right before you enter your loop.

Running this code might help understand what is going wrong:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test')
for i in range(2):
    print i
    parser.add_argument("--file")
    parser.add_argument("stuff")
```

You'll notice that there's an error the second time through the loop, because you already added an argument called "--file".

Comment: that makes so much sense! just removed the argparser.add's from the loop and put them in my setup, works fine now! thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @mhodgy if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.